# jQuery doesn't like breaks in strings?

Tags: jquery

I'm writing some jQuery to modify options in a form. I noticed that when I use .append() for multiple elements at once it will work like this:

```
$("#item").append("<option>Item 1</option><option>Item 2</option><option>Item3</option>");
```

But if I try to clean it up so it's not such a long unreadable line like this:

```
$("#item").append("<option>Item 1</option>
                   <option>Item 2</option>
                   <option>Item3</option>");
```

It won't work? Why? And is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way.

```
$("#item").append("<option>Item 1</option>"+
                   "<option>Item 2</option>"+
                   "<option>Item3</option>");
```

Comment: Ah my stupidity... Thank you haha